# Запрос у DNS сервера IPv6 адреса сайта и ошибка WSANO_DATA (Winsock)

Tags: winapi, winsock

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так ?
Вызываю функцию getaddrinfo() - чтобы получить соответствие доменного имени и его ip-адресса.

```
char my_char_DOMEN[] = "Netflix.com";   //youtube.com, facebook.com ...

const char* my_char_NAME_SERVICE = "https"

//----------------------
ADDRINFOA my_ADDRINFOA;  

my_ADDRINFOA = {};                         
my_ADDRINFOA.ai_family = AF_INET;  //AF_INET6         
//----------------------

struct addrinfo* my_servinfo; 
my_servinfo = {};

getaddrinfo(my_char_DOMEN, my_char_NAME_SERVICE, &my_ADDRINFOA, &my_servinfo);
```

При запросе с AF_INET - все работает отлично ip-адреса возвразаются, но, как только я запрашиваю соответствие с AF_INET6, то getaddrinfo возвращает ошибку WSANO_DATA. C MSDN:

> ```
> Действительное имя, запись данных запрошенного типа отсутствует.
> Запрошенное имя является допустимым и было найдено в базе данных, но
> для него нет правильных связанных данных, для которых выполняется
> разрешение. Обычным примером для этого является попытка преобразования
> имени хоста в адрес (с использованием gethostbyname или
> WSAAsyncGetHostByName ), которая использует DNS (сервер доменных
> имен). Возвращается запись MX, но нет записи A, что указывает на то,
> что сам хост существует, но не доступен напрямую.
> ```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нет так ?

Comment: а что тебе возвращает nslookup Netflix.com?

Comment: Yakov, я вот тут попробовал - https://ping.eu/nslookup. Выдает и ipv4 и ipv6.

Comment: не ты открой cmd напиши nslookup netflix.com, посмотри что он тебе возвращает. потом попробуй написать ping -6 ipv6.google.com и потом сделать выводы из полученных результатов

Comment: Yakov, nslookup netflix.com
╤хЁтхЁ:  UnKnown
Address:  2001:4860:4860::8888

Comment: Yakov, ping -6 ipv6.google.com
При проверке связи не удалось обнаружить узел ipv6.google.com.
Проверьте имя узла и повторите попытку.

Comment: Yakov, а что это значит тогда ? :)

Comment: значит, что твой комп не имеет адреса IPv6, и тоннель в ipv6-сеть тоже не включен (миредо/тередо/исатап и прочее...) вероятно поэтому ты не можешь получить правильный отклик. как вариант может быть потому что ты указываешь   порт https как сервис (для IPv6). но не факт, что такая запись существует. попробуй запросить AAA-запись, порт 53 к примеру.

Comment: возьми не модифицированный пример отсюда https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfoexa каконить и замени адрес на нетфлиск твой и посмотри на результат.

Comment: Yakov, только ipv4 возвращает тоже. :(

Comment: Yakov, подсовываю адрес ipv6.google.com - та же самая ошибка - WSANO_DATA.

Comment: у тебя нет IPv6 адреса, или есть? если есть примеры с MSDN должны работать.

Comment: Yakov, провайдер не поддерживает ipv6. Но, неужели - это значит, что я не смогу из за этого просто достучатся до сайта, который как раз поддерживает ipv6? А что если у этого сайта нет дубя по ipv4 ? Он что поучается для 70-80% интернет пользователей будет недоступен ?

Comment: большая часть интернета уже давно на ipv6 в развитых странах. он удобнее провайдеру, там нет ограничений на количество свободных адресов проще маршрутизация, можно выдать адрес любому холодильнику, безопасность, нет необходимости в арп и прочие удобные плюшки. попробуйте настроить miredo / teredo, тогда должно заработать. на винде не пробовал в линуксе миредо точно работал. еще лет 10 назад пробовал.

Comment: Yakov, подскажите пожалуйста, а обратная ситуация тоже возможна ? Когда у клиента ipv6, а сайт работает на сервере у которого Только ipv4 - клиент тоже не сможет сконнектится с сервером в этом случае ?

Comment: ну через много лет наверное так и будет, а пока или дуалстек с двумя адресами, или ipv4 адрес без ipv6. скорее всего ipv4 адрес ipv6 клиенту днс не вернет, либо  он его расширит до ffff::1:2:3:4 и шлюз смаршрутизирует в ipv4 сеть